# "taste different" or "taste differently"?

Tags: difference, adjectives, adverbs

Tell me please if it correct *different* or *differently* in the following sentence.

> But eggs can taste **different**/**differently** depending on how fresh they are, the way they're cooked and the diet of the hen.

This passage is from this [article](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/white-vs-brown-eggs#section4) and the author uses the word *different* there. Tell me please why.